# How can i create a smoke effect with heart shape in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I want to create a animation like a heart shaped smoke effect for my game .so help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use a particle system to make a smoke effect.  There are lots of tutorials online for how to do this.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysReference.html

http://johnstejskal.com/wp/how-to-create-realistic-smoke-in-unity/

2) Make the smoke emit with heart shape using the shape module with Shape set to Mesh
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysShapeModule.html

3) Set the mesh of the shape module to a heart shaped mesh you get from somewhere.  Maybe you can model one in blender, maybe you can download one somewhere, maybe you can import one from svg.  There are many ways to get a heart shaped mesh.  You might even have one already.